# iarcs WORDLIST RUNTIME SEGMENTATION FAULT

Tags: c++, runtime, segmentation-fault

**WHY THE FOLLOWING GIVES SEGMENTATION ERROR AS REPORTED BY IARCS?**

I wrote the program in Codeblocks and it compiles and runs fine. But g++ reports runtime seg error. Why is this so? The question is :

In this question the input will consist of a number of lines of English text consisting of the letters of the English alphabet, the punctuation marks ' (apostrophe), . (full stop), , (comma), ; (semicolon), :(colon) and white space characters (blank, newline).
Your task is print the words in the text in lexicographic order (that is, dictionary order). Each word should appear exactly once in your list. You can ignore the case (for instance, "The" and "the" are to be treated as the same word.) There should be no uppercase letters in the output.

For example, consider the following candidate for the input text:
This is a sample piece of text to illustrate this 
question.

The corresponding output would read as:

a
illustrate
is
of
piece
problem
sample
text
this
to

Input format

The first line of input contains a single integer N, indicating the number of lines in the input. This is followed by N lines of input text.

Output format

The first line of output contains a single integer M indicating the number of distinct words in the given text. The next M lines list out these words in lexicographic order.

Test data

You may assume that N ≤ 10000 and that there are at most 80 characters in each line. You may also assume that there are at the most 1000 distinct words in the given text.

Example

We now illustrate the input and output formats using the above example.

Sample input

2

This is a sample piece of text to illustrate this

problem.

Sample output

10

a

illustrate

is

of

piece

problem

sample

text

this

to

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

int intcompare(const void *i, const void *j)
{
    return (strcmp(*(char **)i, *(char **)j));
}

void strToLower(char *str)
{
    int i, count=0;
    for (i = 0; *str != '\0'; i++)
    {
        *str = (char)tolower(*str);
        str++;
        count++;
    }

    while((count--)!=0) str--;
}

int main()
{
    int noOfLines, maxCharPerLine=80;
    char delim[]= {'\'', '.', ',', ';', ':', '\n', ' '};
    char line[maxCharPerLine+1];

    cin>>noOfLines;
    cin.get(); 
    char *tokens[maxCharPerLine+1];
    char *temp; 
    int tokcount=-1;

    int flag;
    for(int i=1; i<=noOfLines; i++) 
    {

       cin.getline(line, maxCharPerLine+1); /
        flag=0;
        temp=strtok(line, delim);
        strToLower(temp);
        tokens[++tokcount]=(char *)malloc(maxCharPerLine+1);
        strcpy(tokens[tokcount], temp);
        while(temp!=NULL) 
        {

            strToLower(temp);
            if(flag==1)
            {
                if((char *)bsearch(&temp, tokens, tokcount+1, sizeof(tokens[0]), intcompare)==NULL) {
                    tokens[++tokcount]=(char *)malloc(maxCharPerLine+1);
                    strcpy(tokens[tokcount], temp);
                    qsort(tokens, tokcount+1, sizeof(tokens[0]), intcompare);
                }
            }
            temp= strtok(NULL, delim);
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    cout<<tokcount+1<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<=tokcount; i++)
    {
        cout<<tokens[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you think the error is?  What have you tried so far to debug the program?  Right now it looks like you want us to fix your broken homework assignment for you without having put in any effort to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you see a SEGFAULT, your next step (unless you know right away what you did wrong) is to pull up GDB or another debugger.  If you used GCC and didn't compile your program with the -ggdb flag, do so now.  Then fire up your program under GDB and 'run' it.  When the segfault occurs, issue the command 'bt' (backtrace), and it should show you the current call chain, which is a roadmap of where in the program you were when it segfaulted.  Usually that points you right to the problem.  If not, at least you know where to do some more debugging.